# Send json in v-model vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have input with the name `profile` that is basically binded from data as:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            profile: {
                    phone: +123 123 123;
                 }
            }
       }
```

In the input I specify `name` as `profile` and `v-model` as `profile.phone`. It is sent to backend in the format:

`name: profile, value: +123 123 123`.

I obviously need to get also the information of the field specified - the phone. It is usually performed by sending name as `profile.phone` but the backend expects it as:

`name: profile
 value: {phone: +123 123 123}`

The data are sent by sending all data from `data`. If I want to perform the reformatting that, how do I do that?

Comment: uses [Vue Guide: computed property or watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using re-declaring your object with `let` & `this` keywords.  This will allow you to declare the owner of the function. so you can re-format as:

```
let profileValue = {
    name: 'profile',
    value: {
        phone: this.profile.phone
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the data to your back-end server using probably @click event that triggers your POST method? ...

Inside your method you need to construct your object like this...

```
let profileObj = {
    name: 'profile',
    value: {
        phone : this.profile.phone
    }
}
```